# Copying Files From One Zip File Into Another In Gradle

Tags: gradle

We are working on migrating to Gradle from Maven. Unfortunately we still have a couple of War overlays to deal with.

As a work-around I am trying to copy the contents of one war file into another.

This is what I have so far:

```
task overlayWars (dependsOn: war) << {
    // Get the source war files to copy the contents from...
    def dependencyWars = configurations.runtime.filter { it.name.endsWith ('.war') }
    dependencyWars.each { dependentWar ->

        // Get the products, ie the target war file...
        war.outputs.files.each { product ->
            println "Copying $dependentWar contents into $product"
            copy {
                from { zipTree (dependentWar) }
                into { zipTree (product)}   // this seems to be the problem
                include 'WEB-INF/classes/**/*.class'
                include 'WEB-INF/jsp/**/*.jsp'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When `into { zipTree (product)}` is a file (like `file ('tmp/whatever')`) this works fine. When specifying another zip file (the target war file) it fails with the error:

> Converting class
>   org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter to File using
>   toString() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed
>   in Gradle 2.0. Please use java.io.File, java.lang.String,
>   java.net.URL, or java.net.URI instead.

If anyone has suggestions on this specifically, or a better way to "overlay"  war files, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

After chasing down a couple of different angles, I ended up with this:

```
war {
    configurations.runtime.filter { it.name.endsWith ('.war') }.each {
        from zipTree (it).matching {
            include 'WEB-INF/classes/**/*.class'
            include 'WEB-INF/jsp/**/*.jsp'
            include 'images/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I am just including filtered contents of any .war dependencies in the product. Being an alteration to the standard war task, the dependency tree is kept clean. It seems to work for us so far...

Comment: Great answer thanks for saving me tons of time!  This pattern is very flexible -> I simply needed to include some resources from a dependency that used to be a dependent project, but now is released separately!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying to merge Wars here, you can't do that with a `Copy` task/method. You'll have to use a `Zip` task (there is no equivalent method). In case you want to merge into an existing War, the way to do this is `existingWar.from { zipTree(otherWar) }`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - you are absolutely correct. BTW, how would you create an "existingWar" from a .war on the filesystem? I see how to create a new one, but not how to reference/load an existing one...

Comment: You can't. You'd create a `Zip` task and merge the Wars.

Comment: Can you give a full example on how to do this please.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - Yes, a working example would be great help. TIA!